# LINQ join 2 lists

Tags: sql, .net, linq

I want to select my products regarding their tags. I pass a list of tags to the method. Each product can have one or many tags, each tag can be applied to one or many products.

I can't manage to translate in LINQ, but in SQL the query would be :

```
SELECT * 
FROM products, tagproducts, tags
where products.productId = tagproducts.Product_productId
and tagproducts.Tag_tagId = tags.tagId
and tags.tagId IN (1,2);
```

I guess i have to use join, but can't find a way to get what i want.. Any idea?

Comment: If you don't have `tagproducts` in the model (as your comment on one of the deleted answers) how are you going to get data from it? Add it to the mode and then use @DavidG answer.

Comment: Oh can I? I thought as it was automaticaly generated i must not add it in the model, but i can give a try ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cs
var tagIDs = new List<int> { 1, 2 };
var products = Products.Where(x => x.TagProducts.Any(y => tagIDs.Contains(y.TagID )));
//to get info from the products, . into them
var tagNames = products.TagProducts.Select(x => x.Tags.TagName); //or whatever.
```